# bootstrapping Web Api in Web Forms 3.5 project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, webforms

I have added a Web Api project to my web form solution. Now I'm trying to bootstrap the Web Api from within my web form project.

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApi.WebApiConfig.Register) 
End Sub
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
'Configure' is not a member of 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration'.
```

How do I go about bootstrapping the Web API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have arranged the syntax 'backwards'...Try this:

```
 WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
```

Comment: I'll try to chase that error a little bit this am if I get a chance...I'd recommend that you create a entirely new project in VS choosing VB / MVC / WebApi *and use that project as a reference*.  Make sense?

Comment: Fixed the first problem. I'm now getting the following error when I run the application:  The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code.